# Resonance in Cyclohexenone

Tags: resonance

I don't think that cyclohexenone should have any resonance forms. Moving the double bond around would necessitate moving hydrogens around as well. For example, I know that benzene exhibits resonance (duh) and the second picture attached shows the pi bonding electrons shifting but doesn't show any hydrogens shifting positions.

[image]

[image]

That being said, is there a easier way to determine if a resonance form of a cyclic compound is valid? Drawing out each individual atom and bond is time-consuming! Should I use Huckel's rule? Do all cyclic compounds which exhibit resonance follow Huckel's rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structure you've drawn on the left does have a resonance structure, but not the one you've drawn on the right.

[image]

Drawing resonance structures out by hand gets quicker over time.  You find that you don't need to actually put in a "C" for carbon, or label the hydrogen atoms.  Huckel's rule generally applies to planar, cyclic molecules with continuous conjugation, although it has also be applied to transition states where an S or P orbital on a shifting C or H moiety completes a loop of continuous conjugation (for example, the 1,5 hydrogen shift in cyclopentadiene).